# PHP substr but keep HTML tags?

Tags: php, substr

I am wondering if there is an elegant way to trim some text but while being HTML tag aware?

For example, I have this string:

```
$data = '<strong>some title text here that could get very long</strong>';
```

And let's say I need to return/output this string on a page but would like it to be no more than X characters.  Let's say 35 for this example.

Then I use:

```
$output = substr($data,0,20);
```

But now I end up with:

```
<strong>some title text here that
```

which as you can see the closing strong tags are discarded thus breaking the HTML display.

Is there a way around this?  Also note that it is possible to have multiple tags in the string for example:

```
<p>some text here <strong>and here</strong></p>
```

Comment: Do you need to keep any of the tags? You could use `strip_tags()` to take the tags out, trim the text and use it; add new `<p></p>` if they are needed.

Comment: I don't know if it's an option, but maybe you can use a browser-side solution like `text-overflow: ellipsis` or `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: How complex is the html going to be? Are you stuffing entire chunks of a DOM tree, or just a tag or two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP substr() and strip_tags() while retaining formatting and without breaking HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398725/using-php-substr-and-strip-tags-while-retaining-formatting-and-without-break)

Comment: Yes it needs to retain HTML tags, hence the title or else I could simply use strip_tags...And no it will not be complicated...Just few tags and possibly nested tags..

Answer (score 7):

A few mounths ago I created a special function which is solution for your problem.

Here is a function:

```
function substr_close_tags($code, $limit = 300)
{
    if ( strlen($code) <= $limit )
    {
        return $code;
    }

    $html = substr($code, 0, $limit);
    preg_match_all ( "#<([a-zA-Z]+)#", $html, $result );

    foreach($result[1] AS $key => $value)
    {
        if ( strtolower($value) == 'br' )
        {
            unset($result[1][$key]);
        }
    }
    $openedtags = $result[1];

    preg_match_all ( "#</([a-zA-Z]+)>#iU", $html, $result );
    $closedtags = $result[1];

    foreach($closedtags AS $key => $value)
    {
        if ( ($k = array_search($value, $openedtags)) === FALSE )
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            unset($openedtags[$k]);
        }
    }

    if ( empty($openedtags) )
    {
        if ( strpos($code, ' ', $limit) == $limit )
        {
            return $html."...";
        }
        else
        {
            return substr($code, 0, strpos($code, ' ', $limit))."...";
        }
    }

    $position = 0;
    $close_tag = '';
    foreach($openedtags AS $key => $value)
    {   
        $p = strpos($code, ('</'.$value.'>'), $limit);

        if ( $p === FALSE )
        {
            $code .= ('</'.$value.'>');
        }
        else if ( $p > $position )
        {
            $close_tag = '</'.$value.'>';
            $position = $p;
        }
    }

    if ( $position == 0 )
    {
        return $code;
    }

    return substr($code, 0, $position).$close_tag."...";
}
```

Here is DEMO: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/899d8137c15596a8528c871543eb005984ec0201 (click "Execute code" to check how it works).

Comment: Upvoted for offering a code solution, rather than a link to a third party website (which was down at the time of commenting).

Comment: text inside <pre> returns the whole text. Test $string = <<<'EOT'
<pre class="lang-php prettyprint prettyprinted">
jhfhjfghjfghjfghfghjfghjfghfgjhfgjhghjfgjfghjghjf
ghjfghjfgjhfghjfghjfgjhfghjfghjfghjfgjfghjfghjfgh
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</pre>
EOT;

Answer (score 0):

Using @newbieuser his function, I had the same issue, like @pablo-pazos, that it was (not) breaking when $limit fell into an html tag (in my case `<br />` at the r)

Fixed with some code

```
if ( strlen($code) <= $limit ){
    return $code;
}

$html = substr($code, 0, $limit);       

//We must find a . or > or space so we are sure not being in a html-tag!
//In my case there are only <br>
//If you have more tags, or html formatted text, you must do a little more and also use something like http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php

$_find_last_char = strrpos($html, ".")+1;
if($_find_last_char > $limit/3*2){
    $html_break = $_find_last_char;
}else{
    $_find_last_char = strrpos($html, ">")+1;
    if($_find_last_char > $limit/3*2){ 
        $html_break = $_find_last_char;
    }else{
        $html_break = strrpos($html, " ");
    }
}

$html = substr($html, 0, $html_break);
preg_match_all ( "#<([a-zA-Z]+)#", $html, $result );
......
```

Answer (score -4):

substr(strip_tags($content), 0, 100)

Comment: he want to keep the tags... not remove them.