# php substr - does it know to end html tags?

Tags: php, html, substr

I'm creating my own personal blog, where I can create blog entries. on the front end of my website, it will show part of the blog entry, and users will have to click the "Read More" to read the whole entry.

At the moment, I'm using substr to cut off the blog entry (which is html formatted), I was wondering if that would give me problems with html tags not being closed because of the html cut off, or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: substr() is exactly what it says in the documentation, it is not HTML-aware, so unless you test for html tags it won't do it for you

Comment: In other words, Yes. If you cut in the wrong place you will break you HTML

Comment: `substr(strip_tags($whatever), 0, 100);` very quick method

Comment: or see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933491/php-substr-but-keep-html-tags

Comment: Not in the scope of this question, but @Dale's suggestion will still cut right into words..

Comment: If a person who ask a question on stackoverflow gets a relevant/good answer within a minute after posting the question, then I would say that the person haven't tried enough before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function strip_tags() to strip off every HTML and PHP tags from a given str and then you can use substr() on the same str to cut off your blog entry

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php