# PHP substr() messing style due to closing brackets

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Scenario :

1. I have used a text editor to input my large content ( Wordpress ).
2. So, now the content is to be displayed at homepage so i use the php queries  to display the content.
3. Now, i need the content to be in a size of 100-200 so i have used substr() function of php in order to do so.
4. Also, i need the content to be displayed with different html tags involved in my homepage.

Function Code:

```
$text = get_field('independent_excerpt', $post->ID);
if (strlen($text) > $length) {
   $text = substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',$length)) . '<a class="link_custom_evidenz" href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Leggi Tutto]</a>'; 
}
```

Output Code:

```
<?php echo cstom_function_excerpt(100); ?>
```

So the  above code o/p's the contents correctly but the content breaks my other div's and styles becasuse due to substr() function the html tags are not being properly closed.

So, my question is how do i solve this issue of self closing the html tags when i use the substr() function so that my style's and layout does not end of messing ??

I have searched this issue but failed to achieve any related and good answer. So, please help me to solve this issue.. !!

Thanx

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/8933491/4323504

Comment: @LuthandoLoot Thanx mate.. I will see this thread and get back on my result. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$text = get_field('independent_excerpt', $post->ID);
if (strlen($text) > $length) {
$text = substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',$length));
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
$text = str_replace("'", '`', $text);

    $text. '<a class="link_custom_evidenz" href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Leggi Tutto]</a>'; 



}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Maybe you should have tested this first.