# Using substr() in a MySQL query

Tags: php, string, function

I use this function `substr(tbarticles.articlebody,1,200) as description1` in a query but for some articles I see that the table layout change and page layout also change. It seems that it counts html characters also. Please let me know how can I fix it?

I used also `mb_substr`  but it doesn't return anything for `description1`.

Comment: The database sees this as a string, there's no way for it know that it's HTML.  You're gonna need to parse the HTML with PHP, and then shorten the values to 200 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rocket says you will need to use php, here is a function taken from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398725/using-php-substr-and-strip-tags-while-retaining-formatting-and-without-break):-

```
function html_cut($text, $max_length)
{
$tags   = array();
$result = "";

$is_open   = false;
$grab_open = false;
$is_close  = false;
$in_double_quotes = false;
$in_single_quotes = false;
$tag = "";

$i = 0;
$stripped = 0;

$stripped_text = strip_tags($text);

while ($i < strlen($text) && $stripped < strlen($stripped_text) && $stripped < $max_length)
{
    $symbol  = $text{$i};
    $result .= $symbol;

    switch ($symbol)
    {
       case '<':
            $is_open   = true;
            $grab_open = true;
            break;

       case '"':
           if ($in_double_quotes)
               $in_double_quotes = false;
           else
               $in_double_quotes = true;

        break;

        case "'":
          if ($in_single_quotes)
              $in_single_quotes = false;
          else
              $in_single_quotes = true;

        break;

        case '/':
            if ($is_open && !$in_double_quotes && !$in_single_quotes)
            {
                $is_close  = true;
                $is_open   = false;
                $grab_open = false;
            }

            break;

        case ' ':
            if ($is_open)
                $grab_open = false;
            else
                $stripped++;

            break;

        case '>':
            if ($is_open)
            {
                $is_open   = false;
                $grab_open = false;
                array_push($tags, $tag);
                $tag = "";
            }
            else if ($is_close)
            {
                $is_close = false;
                array_pop($tags);
                $tag = "";
            }

            break;

        default:
            if ($grab_open || $is_close)
                $tag .= $symbol;

            if (!$is_open && !$is_close)
                $stripped++;
    }

    $i++;
}

while ($tags)
    $result .= "</".array_pop($tags).">";

return $result;
}
```

**Edit:** I suspect the reason your page layout is changing is because substr is breaking your html. What you need to do is return all of `tbarticles.articlebody` and once you have it in a variable in the php (e.g. `$result['articlebody']`) then use the function below to trim it to the correct length.

So something like:-

```
 # Get entire field from database, don't use substr
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT tbarticles.articlebody as description1 FROM your_table");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

 # Now make the description the correct length using the function above
 $short_description = html_cut($row['description1'], 200);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess that works.  Personally, I'd use a DOM parser, like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: @rgvcorley;thanks, i'm biginner in php and i'm testing your codes.

Comment: @rgvcorley, i have confused because it is inside query ,and i must say that it is not important for me the number of character that return,but it is important that my page layout does not change,please send me an example.how i must use your function?

Comment: You asked about substr - which extracts part of a string. I have no idea about your page layout so unless restricting the number of characters is going to stop your page layout from being changed then you'll need to give more information for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks,your solution with html_cut() is ok.