# PHP substr() function that allows you to set start and stop point AND keeps HTML formatting?

Tags: php, html, formatting, split, substr

With the normal `substr()` function in PHP you have the ability to decide where you want to "start" cutting the string, as well as set as setting the length. The length is probably used the most, but in this case i need to cut off about 120 characters from the beginning. The problem is that i need to keep the html in the string intact, and only cut the actual text within the tags.

I found a few custom functions for it, but i haven't found a single one that allows you to set a starting point, eg. where you want to start cutting the string.

Here's one i found: [Using PHP substr() and strip_tags() while retaining formatting and without breaking HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398725/using-php-substr-and-strip-tags-while-retaining-formatting-and-without-break)

So, i basically need a `substr()` function that works exactly the same as the original one, except keeps formatting.

Any suggestions?

Example content to modify:

```
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going <a href="#">through the cites</a> of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus</p> <p>Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the <strong>Renaissance</strong>. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
```

After cutting off 5 from the start:

```
<p>ary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going <a href="#">through the cites</a> of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus</p> <p>Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the <strong>Renaissance</strong>. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
```

And 5 off the beginning AND end:

```
<p>ary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going <a href="#">through the cites</a> of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus</p> <p>Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the <strong>Renaissance</strong>. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.1</p>
```

Yeah, you catch my drift?

I would prefer if it cut off the entire word if it was to stop cutting in the middle of one, but it's not super important.

** Edit: ** Fixed quotes.

Comment: Please post the string you need to modify. There may be a better way than substr()

Comment: There is not one specific string i need to modify, it's going to differ. It's basically a bunch of `<p>` tags and maybe a few `<a>`, `<strong>` etc inside. It's the content of a blog page, created by a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Post a _sample_ then.  For HTML created by a haphazard wysiwyg, you're going to have a very hard time with substr.  May be a job for a proper DOM parser.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you expect when cutting off the beginning of a string?

Comment: Alright guys, please see sample content in OP.@MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many complications involved in what you are asking (essentially, generate a valid html subset given a *string* offset), that it would really be better if you reformulate your problem in such a way that it is expressed as the number of *text characters* you want to keep rather than as cutting an arbitrary string which has html in it.  If you do that this problem becomes much easier because you can use a real HTML parser. You will not need to worry about:

- Accidentally cutting elements in half.
- Accidentally cutting *entites* in half.
- Not counting text inside elements.
- Making sure a character entity counts as a single character.
- Making sure all elements are properly closed.
- Making sure you don't destroy the string because you're using `substr()` on a utf-8 string.

It is *possible* to accomplish this with regexes (using the `u` flag) and `mb_substr()` and a tag stack (I've done it before), but there are many edge cases and you are generally in for a hard slog.

However, a DOM solution is fairly straightforward: walk through all the text nodes counting up string lengths and either remove or substring their text content as needed. The code below does this:

```php
$html = <<<'EOT'
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going <a href="#">through the cites</a> of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus</p> <p>Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the <strong>Renaissance</strong>. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
EOT;
```

```php
function substr_html($html, $start, $length=null, $removeemptyelements=true) {
    if (is_int($length)) {
        if ($length===0) return '';
        $end = $start + $length;
    } else {
        $end = null;
    }
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTML('<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"><title></title></head><body>'.$html.'</body>');
    $body = $d->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    $dxp = new DOMXPath($d);
    $t_start = 0; // text node's start pos relative to all text
    $t_end   = null; // text node's end pos relative to all text

    // copy because we may modify result of $textnodes
    $textnodes = iterator_to_array($dxp->query('/descendant::*/text()', $body));

// PHP 5.2 doesn't seem to implement Traversable on DOMNodeList,
// so `iterator_to_array()` won't work. Use this instead:
// $textnodelist = $dxp->query('/descendant::*/text()', $body);
// $textnodes = array();
// for ($i = 0; $i < $textnodelist->length; $i++) {
//  $textnodes[] = $textnodelist->item($i);
//}
//unset($textnodelist);

    foreach($textnodes as $text) {
        $t_end = $t_start + $text->length;
        $parent = $text->parentNode;
        if ($start >= $t_end || ($end!==null && $end < $t_start)) {
            $parent->removeChild($text);
        } else {
            $n_offset = max($start - $t_start, 0);
            $n_length = ($end===null) ? $text->length : $end - $t_start;
            if (!($n_offset===0 && $n_length >= $text->length)) {
                $substr = $text->substringData($n_offset, $n_length);
                if (strlen($substr)) {
                    $text->deleteData(0, $text->length);
                    $text->appendData($substr);
                } else {
                    $parent->removeChild($text);
                }
            }
        }

        // if removing this text emptied the parent of nodes, remove the node!
        if ($removeemptyelements && !$parent->hasChildNodes()) {
            $parent->parentNode->removeChild($parent);
        }

        $t_start = $t_end;
    }
    unset($textnodes);
    $newstr = $d->saveHTML($body);

    // mb_substr() is to remove <body></body> tags
    return mb_substr($newstr, 6, -7, 'utf-8');
}


echo substr_html($html, 480, 30);
```

This will output:

```
<p> of "de Finibus</p> <p>Bonorum et Mal</p>
```

Notice it is not confused by the fact that your "substring" spans multiple `p` elements.

Comment: That looks awesome! I'm getting an error on PHP 5.2.17 though. See here: http://pastebin.com/HvVN19tR Do i need to include something else? Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the `Traversable` interface was not implemented in `DOMNodeList` in 5.2.17. (I can't vouch for this code as-is in anything less than 5.3.) I amended the answer with a workaround, but you should upgrade to 5.3 if possible.

Comment: I will give that a try as soon as i can, thank you! I'll see what i can do about upgrading PHP. I might just wait for 5.5 to pop out and upgrade then, because i'm gonna want to play around with that for sure.

Comment: The new code did it's job, but `$d->saveHTML($body);` doesn't seem to be 5.2 compatible. I did a little bit of digging and found that `saveXml()` yields almost the same result (not sure what differs, it works fine for me). Please include it in your answer as well in case anyone else runs into the same issue. I also just realized it would be much better if it completed the last sentence, but i won't bother changing that, unless it's a simple edit?

Comment: `SaveXML` is *not* a suitable replacement. It will self-close elements that can't be in HTML. As a workaround use the normal `saveHTML()` without an argument and use `preg_match()` to grab the stuff inside the `body` element (or `preg_replace()` to remove the stuff outside it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start, utilizing `DOMDocument` (a xml/html parser), `RecursiveIteratorIterator` (for easy traversal of recursive structures) and custom `DOMNodeList` iterator implementations, to play nice with `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.

It's all still pretty sloppy (doesn't return a copy, but acts on the reference of the `DOMNode`/`DOMDocument`), and it doesn't have the fancy functionalities of the regular `substr()`, such as negative values for `$start` and/or `$length`, but it seems to do the job, so far. I'm sure there are bugs though. But it should give you an idea on how to go about doing this with `DOMDocument`.

Custom iterators:

```
class DOMNodeListIterator
    implements Iterator
{
    protected $domNodeList;

    protected $position;

    public function __construct( DOMNodeList $domNodeList )
    {
        $this->domNodeList = $domNodeList;
        $this->rewind();
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return $this->position < $this->domNodeList->length;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        $this->position++;
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->domNodeList->item( $this->position );
    }
}

class RecursiveDOMNodeListIterator
    extends DOMNodeListIterator
    implements RecursiveIterator
{
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return $this->current()->hasChildNodes();
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return new self( $this->current()->childNodes );
    }
}
```

The actual function:

```
function DOMSubstr( DOMNode $domNode, $start = 0, $length = null )
{
    if( $start == 0 && ( $length == null || $length >= strlen( $domNode->nodeValue ) ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    $nodesToRemove = array();
    $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDOMNodeListIterator( $domNode->childNodes ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
    foreach( $rii as $node )
    {
        if( $start <= 0 && $length !== null && $length <= 0 )
        {
            /* can't remove immediately
             * because this will mess with
             * iterating over RecursiveIteratorIterator
             * so remember for removal, later on
             */
            $nodesToRemove[] = $node;
            continue;
        }

        if( $node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE )
        {
            if( $start > 0 )
            {
                $count = min( $node->length, $start );
                $node->deleteData( 0, $count );
                $start -= $count;
            }

            if( $start <= 0 )
            {
                if( $length == null )
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if( $length <= 0 )
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if( $length >= $node->length )
                {
                    $length -= $node->length;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    $node->deleteData( $length, $node->length - $length );
                    $length = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach( $nodesToRemove as $node )
    {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild( $node );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p>Just a short text sample with <a href="#">a link</a> and some trailing elements such as <strong>strong text<strong>, <em>emphasized text</em>, <del>deleted text</del> and <ins>inserted text</ins></p>
HTML;

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
/*
 * this is particularly sloppy:
 * I pass $dom->firstChild->nextSibling->firstChild (i.e. <body>)
 * because the function uses strlen( $domNode->nodeValue )
 * which will be 0 for DOMDocument itself
 * and I didn't want to utilize DOMXPath in the function
 * but perhaps I should have
 */
DOMSubstr( $dom->firstChild->nextSibling->firstChild, 8, 25 );

/*
 * passing a specific node to DOMDocument::saveHTML()
 * only works with PHP >= 5.3.6
 */
echo $dom->saveHTML( $dom->firstChild->nextSibling->firstChild->firstChild );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this one, if its not longer text (because of the runtime).

> but in this case i need to cut off about 120 characters from the beginning.

Exactly doing this. Enter your text or grab it from somewhere and enter the number of character it shall erase from the beginning.

**And please, can't stress that enough : Its a solution for short strings and its not the best way to do so,  but its a complete working codesample!**

```
<?php
$text = "<a href='blablabla'>m</a>ylinks...<b>not this code is working</b>......";
$newtext = "";
$delete = 13;
$tagopen = false;

while ($text != ""){
    $checktag=$text[0];
    $text=substr( $text, 1 );
    if ($checktag =="<" || $tagopen == TRUE){
        $newtext .= $checktag;
        if ($checktag == ">"){
        $tagopen = FALSE;
        }
        else{
        $tagopen = TRUE;
        }
    }
    elseif ($delete > 0){   
        $delete = $delete -1 ;
        }
    else
    {
    $newtext .= $checktag;

    }
}
echo $newtext;



?>
```

it returns:

```
<a href='blablabla'></a><b> this code is working</b>......
```

Comment: What about escaped characters, such as &copy; or similar? I assume they will get cut off in the middle? I also need to be able to cut from both ways, not just the beginning.

Comment: if you intend to cut both ways and escape special characters as well, i have to agree with Michael Berkowski as he commented to your question. I had the question in the first version (as i qouted as well) you said a from beginning, but didnt think of escaped chars.  Sorry

Comment: Alright then! A DOM parser would be fine, could you recommend a fast-to-setup and easy-to-use one?