# PHP substr breaks my table

Tags: php, substr

I have a table like so

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';

                echo '<td>' . $value['title'] . '</td>';

                echo '<td>' . $value['date'] . '</td>';

                echo '<td>' . $value['preview'] . '</td>';

                echo '<td>' . substr($value['description'], 0, 10) . '</td>';

                echo '<td><img src="../images/articles/' . $value['image'] . '"></td>';

                echo '<td><img src="../images/articles/' . $value['detailImage'] . '"></td>';

                        if($value['showDetailImage'] == 1){
                                $showDetailImage = 'Yes';
                        }else{
                                $showDetailImage = 'No';
                        }

                echo '<td>' . $showDetailImage . '</td>';

                echo '<td><a class="btn btn-default" href="Press.php?action=edit&id=' . $value['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a onclick="if(!confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this item?\')) return false;" class="btn btn-default" href="Press.php?action=delete&id=' . $value['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';

                echo '</tr>';
                echo '</table>';
```

notice I have `substr` and when I have that in there, it does not display the description and breaks the rest of my table, if I remove the substr the table is fine and everything is displayed. Why is `substr` breaking my table.

Comment: Let me guess, `$value['description']` contains HTML markup? You should *always* escape HTML output.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398725/using-php-substr-and-strip-tags-while-retaining-formatting-and-without-break?rq=1) seems to be related.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the description would contain?

Comment: Another reason this might fail is that substr() will happily slice through the middle of a character when using UTF-8, using mb_substr() helps in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the contents of description that contains HTML markup that's breaking the table, use `htmlspecialchars`...

```
echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars(substr($value['description'], 0, 10)) . '</td>';
```

Comment: This may not have the desired effect, because it will just show HTML as is :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that because your `substr` concatenates half way through some HTML element?

For example, you should use:

```
echo htmlentities(substr($value['description'], 0, 10));
```

Or if you want to strip the HTML tags:

```
echo strip_tags(substr($value['description'], 0, 10));
```

Comment: When using `strip_tags()` you will still want to use `htmlspecialchars()`.