# How to cut an HTML text in PHP without breaking the tags hierarchy

Tags: php, html, text, trim, strip-tags

I'm trying to trim some HTML text and found a thread but can't comment in it yet because I'm new ([Using PHP substr() and strip_tags() while retaining formatting and without breaking HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398725/using-php-substr-and-strip-tags-while-retaining-formatting-and-without-break))

First i create the function *preview* (input: html text or plain text, number of char, boolean if you want plain text output) but when I tried to extend the functionality to work with HTML tags, the problem begin

I used the function `html_cut()` from the other post to close tags but I need some nested tags and I think the function closed every tag it found so it breaks the hierarchy. (Is it in fact the problem or i'm wrong?)

```
function preview($text, $char, $sinhtml){
    if(strlen($text) > $char){
        $post = substr($text, $char, 1);
        if ($post != " "){
            $i = true;
            while($post != " "){
                if($char > 0 && $i){
                    $char--;
                    $post = substr($text, $char, 1);
                }elseif($char == 0){
                    $i = false;
                    $char++;
                }else{
                    $char++;
                    $post = substr($text, $char, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        $post = substr($text, 0, $char);
        $post .= " …";
        if($sinhtml){
            return strip_tags($post);
        }else{
-->         return $post;
        }
    }else{
        return $text;
    }
}
```

The input text is something like this

```
<p> Some text… </p>
<ul>
   <li>Technical Description</li>
   <li>or Details (weight, size, etc.)</li>
   <li>…</li>
</ul>
<p>may be some more text</p>
```

The function `html_cut()` has a line that I´ve never seen before and don´t know what it does… *$symbol = $text{$i}*

```
function html_cut($text, $max_length)
{
    $tags   = array();
    $result = "";

    $is_open   = false;
    $grab_open = false;
    $is_close  = false;
    $in_double_quotes = false;
    $in_single_quotes = false;
    $tag = "";

    $i = 0;
    $stripped = 0;

    $stripped_text = strip_tags($text);

    while ($i < strlen($text) && $stripped < strlen($stripped_text) && $stripped < $max_length)
    {
        $symbol  = $text{$i};
        $result .= $symbol;

        switch ($symbol)
        {
           case '<':
                $is_open   = true;
                $grab_open = true;
                break;

           case '"':
               if ($in_double_quotes)
                   $in_double_quotes = false;
               else
                   $in_double_quotes = true;

            break;

            case "'":
              if ($in_single_quotes)
                  $in_single_quotes = false;
              else
                  $in_single_quotes = true;

            break;

            case '/':
                if ($is_open && !$in_double_quotes && !$in_single_quotes)
                {
                    $is_close  = true;
                    $is_open   = false;
                    $grab_open = false;
                }

                break;

            case ' ':
                if ($is_open)
                    $grab_open = false;
                else
                    $stripped++;

                break;

            case '>':
                if ($is_open)
                {
                    $is_open   = false;
                    $grab_open = false;
                    array_push($tags, $tag);
                    $tag = "";
                }
                else if ($is_close)
                {
                    $is_close = false;
                    array_pop($tags);
                    $tag = "";
                }

                break;

            default:
                if ($grab_open || $is_close)
                    $tag .= $symbol;

                if (!$is_open && !$is_close)
                    $stripped++;
        }

        $i++;
    }

    while ($tags)
        $result .= "</".array_pop($tags).">";

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: post your code. this is a new question and shouldn't be a comment on the old question linked,

Comment: what's the input text? and desired output?

Comment: Is a text from a database, a partial description from a product

Comment: I don't see any relation between the `html_cut` method you refer to and the chunk of code you posted.

Comment: no… this one only cut the html text but if the html text is larger than the char amount it won´t be correctly closed

Comment: the actual data, not some vague description of it

Comment: If you see the arrow (-->), the result of this function could be broken if it has HTML tags open

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) 
or [Tidy HTML.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)
For checking the nested tags

Comment: I need to install the tidy function? the page say (This extension is bundled with PHP 5 and greater, and is installed using the --with-tidy configure option.)
how do i call it

Comment: I was reading the documentation of this functions but I need to work without this set up because is for a self installing system and I can't leave that kind of work to the user because is too confusing