# Wordpress filters and excerpts

Tags: php, html, wordpress, filter

I am trying to pull content from one page into another.  I could be going about this the wrong way, but I am just trying to get the general method of how it is done.  This is what I have so far trying to get the data I need.  I am not getting the permalink or the image.  The other issue is when applying the substr method to the $content variable it actually cuts the html tags off to making it to where anything after it gets nested into whatever html happens to be in the content.  I appreciate any tips you may have.  Here is the function I created to try and pull the content in it's initial stage.

```
function show_post($path) {
  $post = get_page_by_path($path);
  $title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
  $image = apply_filters('featured_image', $post->the_post_thumbnail);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
  $link = apply_filters('the_permalink', $post->get_permalink);
  echo '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
  echo substr($content, 0, 300) . '...';
}
```

$path is the relative url of the website to where I am pulling content so lets say my url i want to grab data is www.test.com/about/bio I would make the path be about/bio.

I appreciate your help in this.

Comment: Try using [setup_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)

Comment: Thank you for this.  This sent me in the right direction for more digging and on hw to query the post using the setup post date.  Would you know how to get the post content in it's normal html and shorten it to 300 characters while retaining the actual html.  right now it is pulling a unordered list and breaking off in the middle of a list element and enclosing everyting around that.

Comment: take a look at [balanceTags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/balanceTags) and also [wp_trim_words](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I actually found: [keep html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398725/using-php-substr-and-strip-tags-while-retaining-formatting-and-without-break)